# Instantiate a variable in Kotlin only if it is a null?

Tags: java, kotlin, nullable, getter, backing-field

Lets say, I have a variable:

`var myObject : MyObject? = null`

it should be cleared in some place :

```
myObject?.clear
myObject = null
```

and should be definitely non-nullable in a place of usage. In Java I can do something like this:

```
private MyObject getMyObject(){
  if(myObject == null) {
    myObject = new MyObject()
  }
  return myObject
}
```

**The question:** How can I achieve that in Kotlin?

I found a suggestion to use elvis-operator:

```
private fun getMyObject() = myObject ?: MyObject()
```

but that does not  assign a result (if new instance of `MyObject` would be created) to the `myObject` variable.
Please help me with solution and explanation. thanks ahead

Comment: You can do it the same like in Java: `private fun getMyObject(): MyObject {
  if(myObject == null) {
    myObject = MyObject()
 }
   return myObject
}`

Comment: @Sergey - of course, I understand that I can use that approach. the question is about the more elegant  solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that the getter and setter of a property can't have different types. I'd suggest a separate nullable private property and a method for clearing it:

```
private var _myObject: MyObject? = null

var myObject: MyObject // or val, depending
    get() {
        if (_myObject == null) { _myObject = MyObject() }
        return _myObject!!
    }
    set(value: MyObject) { 
        _myObject?.clear()
        _myObject = value
    }

fun clearMyObject() {
    _myObject?.clear()
    _myObject = null
}
```

If you need this pattern more than once, write a [delegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields) of the property.

```
class Foo {

    var bar: String? = null
        get() {
            if (field == null) {
                field = "Automatically set"
            }
            return field
        }


}
```

To try it:

```
fun main() {
    val foo = Foo()
    foo.bar = "Manually set"
    println(foo.bar)
    foo.bar = null
    println(foo.bar)
}
```

Unfortunately, the property must be nullable for this to work. You'll have to use `!!` or `?.` everywhere.

---

You could also use a delegate. This takes more code to write the property but makes it easier to use the property elsewhere.

```
class Foo(initBar: String? = null) {

    private val barDelegate = NullDelegate(initBar) { "Automatically set" }
    var bar: String by barDelegate // not nullable to outside world

    fun clearBar() {
        barDelegate.clear()
    }

}

// Reusable. Not thread-safe.
class NullDelegate<T>(
    private var value: T? = null, 
    private val supplier: () -> T
) {

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        if (value == null) value = supplier()
        return value!!
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T?) {
        this.value = value
    }

    fun clear() {
        value = null
    }

}
```

To set `bar` to `null` you'd call `foo.clearBar()` instead of `foo.bar = null`.

Comment: Great way to use delegates!

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the Java-like approach with the usage of Elvis operator, writing something like this:

```
private fun getMyObject() : MyObject {
    myObject = myObject ?: MyObject()
    return myObject as MyObject
}
```

The explicit conversion `as MyObject` is needed because of `myObject`'s declaration: `var myObject MyObject? = null`. `myObject` is a *nullable `MyObject`* but `getObject`'s return type is `MyObject`.
I hope this can help you!

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:**

A shorter version of @Slaw's version is the following:

```
var myObject: MyObject? = null
    get() {
        field = field ?: MyObject()
        return field
    }
```

This will instantiate a new `MyObject` to the backing field if the property is `null` on a `get` access.

---

**Additional info:**

You would probably think of a shorter version similar to the following

```
var myObject: Any? = null
    get() = field = field ?: Any() // Does not compile
```

Please keep in mind that *this does not compile* with the error message:         `Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context`.

Answer (score 2):

You had almost found the right answer with the elvis operator, the only missing part was to assign the newly created instance back to `myObject` variable:

```
private fun getMyObject() = myObject ?: MyObject().also { myObject = it }
```

Comment: best answer ever